# Osmnx: creating a graph from a shapefile/XML

Tags: python, xml, openstreetmap, networkx, osmnx

I'm learning how to do Network Analysis for road networks of countries. I already have the shapefiles. 
I have been trying to convert them to networkx without much success so I'm trying to use the ox.graph_from_file function to do it. Getting country-scale data from osm is time/memory consuming and too detailed for what I want to do.

I converted my shapefile to .xml file using mapshaper but ox.graph_from_file does not work. I just call like it this:

```
ox.graph_from_file('/Users/macbookair/Downloads/road_rmms_v10_3.xml')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
EmptyOverpassResponse                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-5f835eba75d0> in <module>()
----> 1 ox.graph_from_file('/Users/macbookair/Downloads/road_rmms_v10_3.xml')

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osmnx/core.py in graph_from_file(filename, network_type, simplify, retain_all, name)
1898     # create graph using this response JSON
1899     G = create_graph(response_jsons, network_type=network_type,
-> 1900                      retain_all=retain_all, name=name)
1901 
1902     # simplify the graph topology as the last step.

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osmnx/core.py in create_graph(response_jsons, name, retain_all, network_type)
1327         elements.extend(response_json['elements'])
1328     if len(elements) < 1:
-> 1329         raise EmptyOverpassResponse('There are no data elements in the  response JSON objects')
1330 
1331     # create the graph as a MultiDiGraph and set the original CRS to   default_crs

EmptyOverpassResponse: There are no data elements in the response JSON objects
```

I am not sure if I'm calling it wrong or i have the bad file format.

Comment: "I converted my shapefile to .xml file" Why do you use a shapefile in the first place? OSM data is usually stored as PBF or XML. A conversion from XML -> Shapefile -> XML will certainly loose information. Try OSM XML in the first place, either by downloading XML directly or by converting PBF to XML.

Comment: I already have the shapefiles I must use for the task: they only have national roads and highways of some countries. Importing country data from OSM (using osmnx to create the graphs) is not efficient at all, it takes hours.

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong file format. You cannot convert just any file structure to XML and then read it in. Instead, download an extract of OSM data directly as a .osm file in XML format. Then load it [with OSMnx](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.core.graph_from_file).